# Parsing Subsecond Date with Howard Hinnant Date Library

Tags: c++, date

I have a date string like so `YYYYMMDD HHMMSSFFF`. I am trying to use Howard Hinnats date library. Snippet of code is like so,

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
char date[20] = {0};
std::istringstream ss{date};
ss >> date::parse("%Y%m%d %H%M%S%s", tp);

long ts = (std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp)
                     .time_since_epoch() /
                 std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
```

But this code isn't reading the subsecond `FFF`. I loooked on the documentation [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) and it states that `%s` represents fractional of a second time. An example value for date is `20170110 103648340`. But when I output `ts` I get 0. If you are wondering why I convert to nanoseconds its because I need the date in nanoseconds for other operations.

Comment: Have you tried "%Y%m%d %H%M%S.%s" (note the period)?

Comment: I thought the . represented a period in the string, ill give it a go

Comment: If that doesn't work, also try %S, without the .%s afterwards?

Comment: It didn't, and I have also already tried only %S. When I do that the date `20170106 083206493` and `20170106 083206743` both give me `14836905`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %T, it seems to work. Here is an example:

```
#include <date/date.h>
int main()
{
    std::string dt{ "20190501 113001234" };
    dt = dt.insert(11, ":");
    dt = dt.insert(14, ":");
    dt = dt.insert(17, ".");
    // now we have "20190501 11:30:01.234"

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    std::istringstream ss{ dt };
    ss >> date::parse("%Y%m%d %T", tp);

    long ts = (std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp)
        .time_since_epoch() /
        std::chrono::nanoseconds(1));
}
```

Comment: my input string would be `20190501 113001234` where %T would not work.

Comment: Can you inset a . between the seconds and the milliseond before giving it to the date lib, and colons.. I will amend my example.

Comment: yea i tried it out before your edit, it works well although I would call this a janky solution but it is a solution.

Comment: Yes, but you made the rules for the input and date lib works the way it works.
You can also by-parse the date lib if you like and add the milliseconds directly.

Comment: Howard Hinnant's date library makes no distinction between integral seconds and fractional seconds.  There is no concept of `%s`.  Both `%T` and `%S` parse fractional seconds using the decimal point character of the stream's locale.

Answer (score 2):

You could also parse it this way:

```
sys_seconds tp;
int ims;
ss >> parse("%Y%m%d %H%M%2S", tp) >> ims;
return tp + milliseconds{ims};
```

The `%2S` says:  parse as much as 2 chars for the seconds.  That leaves the trailing three digits yet to be parsed.  Pick those up with a integral parse and convert that integer to milliseconds, and you're good.

This won't work if there are trailing digits after the 3 millisecond digits.

Comment: I'm unable to get `date::parse(...)` calls to compile with MSVC 19.34.31933. Fails to find any matching overloads. GCC is fine with same codebase. Is it because the libcpp in MSVC case actually includes `std::chrono::parse`?

Comment: I'm not sure.  If `std::chrono::parse` will do the job, I recommend that.  I would just adjust the namespace between `date` and `std::chrono` with a configuration macro depending on the compiler.  gcc will implement this in 14:  https://wandbox.org/permlink/51Xge7BYHsiKaQPT