# How to parse strings with no decimal point between seconds and subseconds using the C++ date library?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, parsing, std

I am currently working with the external [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) by Howard Hinnant and have a problem with parsing datetime-related strings of the format `HH:mm:ssSSS`. Parsing strings like `HH:mm:ss,SSS` is no problem since I am able to specify the decimal point between seconds and subseconds. Parsing strings like `HH:mm:ssSSS` however does not work.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048426/parsing-subsecond-date-with-howard-hinnant-date-library). However, it does not answer the question how to handle this case via `std::numpunct`. I don't want to alter the string to set a `.` between seconds and subseconds only to handle this special case, especially since this is only one of arbitrarily many cases that I have to handle.

In detail, by using a punctuation facet like described below it is possible to set a custom decimal separator when parsing strings with seconds und subseconds via `date::parse`. However, it appears to be impossible to omit the decimal separator between seconds und subseconds entirely, since (a) `std::numpunct` only works with character types and (b) using a null terminator does not work at all when parsing via the date library.

Hence my question: Is there any way to parse strings like `HH:mm:ssSSS` via `date::parse()` and `std::numpunct`?

```
class PunctuationFacet
    : public std::numpunct<char>
{
public:
   PuncutationFacet(char numericPunctuation, size_t referenceCount = 0)
      : std::numpunct<char>(referenceCount)
      , _numericPunctuation(numericPunctuation)

protected:
    char do_decimal_point() const { return _numericPunctuation; }

private:
    char _numericPunctuation;

std::optional<uin64_t> parse(std::string_view value, char numericPunctuation)
{
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::milliseconds> timepoint;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new PunctuationFacet(numericPunctuation)));
    ss << value;
    ss >> date::parse("%H:%M:%S", timepoint);
    if (ss.fail()) [[unlikely]]
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return timepoint.time_since_epoch().count();
}

int main(int argumentCount, char **arguments)
{
    auto timestampDoesWork = parse("14:20:51,123", ',');
    auto timestampDoesNotWork = parse("14:20:51123", 0);
}
```

Comment: It's easy because you know *exactly* how long the `HH:mm:ss` string is. That means you can create two sub-strings, one for the `HH:mm:ss` part and one for the `SSS` part, and parse them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That is sadly not easily possible since I am writing a hghly flexible parsing interface for a project that has to handle every potential combination of formats. I could get this to work however but I would always have to check if seconds are present in the format at all. But I guess I might have no other option if there is no other way

Comment: I was about to answer when I noticed that @Someprogrammerdude has already said what I was going to say: parse the two whole seconds digits and deal with the reset with custom parsing code.

Comment: You don't need to separate them. Just parse the whole 'seconds' field as yielding a value in milliseconds, and then divide and modulo by 1000 to separate out the seconds and milliseconds values *after* the parse.

Answer (score 0):

[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) answered this in the comments, but after a couple of days without an official answer, I figured it was time to make one.

Neither [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), nor `std::numpunct` (nor C++20 chrono) have a way to parse seconds with an implicit decimal point character.

In the comments below the question it is revealed that the number of digits in the seconds can vary from 0 to some as-yet-specified number.  And this answer does not address that complication.

However, for future readers, here is how you could parse a time duration of the form `HH:mm:ssSSS` into `std::chrono::milliseconds` using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// parse HH:mm:ssSSS
std::chrono::milliseconds
my_parse(std::string t)
{
    std::istringstream in{std::move(t)};
    in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    int ms;
    std::chrono::seconds s;
    in >> date::parse("%T", s) >> ms;
    return s + std::chrono::milliseconds{ms};
}

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << my_parse("14:20:51123") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
51651123ms
```

And this will easily port to C++20 by changing `date::parse` to `std::chrono::parse`.

The trick is to parse into `seconds` first, using `%T` (or the equivalent `%H:%M:%S`), and then parse in the remaining digits as an `int` and convert that `int` to `std::chrono::milliseconds`.  With a fixed number of digits it is pretty easy.

With a variable number of digits one would have to count the digits and interpret them to the proper precision.  Certainly do-able, but would take more code than shown here, and leans more towards "you have to do it yourself".